# removing 'Program Name' in metadata for images

Tags: windows, filesystems, metadata

In Windows file properties, it's called 'Program Name' under Origin.
In Adobe Bridge, it's called 'Application' under File Properties.

I believe it adds the name of the program used to create the file. It cannot be edited/removed in Bridge or Windows.

I really don't understand how it gets added because certain images taken from a camera and edited in Lightroom does not add the attribute, and other times it does. One file was edited in Photoshop and tagged Photoshop, but when imported into Lightroom and exported, the attribute said Windows Photo Viewer instead.

Bottom line, I want the attribute deleted. Can't seem to find a reference to that attribute or how to remove it online.

Comment: If there's a Stack Exchange site related to image manipulation, or perhaps graphic design, that is where this question belongs and should be moved to.  It's a good question and has good answers.  Though I agree it doesn't relate much to programming (beyond that websites are programmed and contain images).

Answer (score 8):

Referring my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43164924/5781956).
I tried all these exiftool software that never worked for me. Assuming you are on Windows (or Windows 10), the solution to the problem was very simple. You can select which property you want to remove. If this worked for you, kindly mark it as the right answer.

[image: Remove Program Name]

Answer (score 3):

If you need a freeware, use [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

[ExifToolGUI for Windows](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/) is a nice GUI for the ExifTool
[image: ExifToolGUI for Windows]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about jpeg images, which probably means exif data. You could try [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) to manipulate that data; as an extreme measure, the `-da` option should remove all exif metadata.

If you're not talking about jpeg images, you should be more specific.

Comment: I only know of tiff and jpg supporting metadata. Are there more?

Comment: png supports tEXt, zTXt, and iTXt chunks to store key-value pairs. gif has a comment block that could be used to store formatted metadata.

Answer (score 1):

gavsiu, try Exifcleaner by Superutils -- it can remove picture metadata selectively:

> [ExifCleaner](http://www.superutils.com/products/exifcleaner/) is a batch photographic
>   utility that lets selectively 
>   remove Exif tags from JPEG photos.

On the Clean Setup - Clean Options pane, check the Software item, and set other boxes unchecked. Hope this helps.

By the way, removing of absolutely all metadata is not a good idea -- it is useful for archiving purposes.