# How to remove 'Program Name' from Images?

Tags: metadata, photo, photoshop, exif

I've tried the solutions from here: [removing 'Program Name' in metadata for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414300/removing-program-name-in-metadata-for-images) but, nothing worked. Is there a way to remove all the 'Photoshop' information from the image and retain the other metadata in it, created by photoshop (eg: name, contact info, copyright info etc.)

EDIT: The 'Program Name' from the properties menu when someone right clicks on an image in windows.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all these exiftool software that never worked for me. Assuming you are on Windows (or Windows 10), the solution to the problem was very simple. You can select which property you want to remove. If this worked for you, kindly mark it as the right answer.

[image: Remove Program Name]

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could post an image, or link, so that we could see what you mean. Maybe you can run:

```
jhead -v -v yourimage.jpg
```

and edit your question and post the output.

In the meantime, you will probably find that one of the following options does what you want:

```
jhead -du -di -dx yourimage.jpg
```

You can test with the first command I gave above.

`jhead` is available from [here](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/).